# view Documents using UIWebview from Server

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I am uploading documents (.png/.doc/.pdf/.xls ETC) on server from website.
I have iPad App from where I need to view them. 
from DB i will get path like D:/Doc/Upload/test.pdf for every document. This is the path of server where document is uploaded.

Is it possible to view them on iPad? After some googling I found out UIWebview support most of the document.
To connect to client server I use VPN. 
From iPAD is it possible to connect to VPN(sonic wall) I have seen in setting.
And can I pass path and I will be able to view uploaded DOC?

Comment: can you vote up my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load server document using below code in UIWebview:

```
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Url"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [YourWebView loadRequest:request];
```

And add UIWebviewDelegate in .h file.

Also check this for UIWebview Document support list [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1630/_index.html)

Comment: ok. but is it possible for VPN setting as i need VPN to connect to server. i hope i am on right track. i am using Sonic wall on windows to connect to server so similar setting i will need to view uploaded documents right?

Comment: I have downloaded mobile connect and connected to VPN successfully. i have doc name, doc path and other info which i am getting from database. doc path like D:\DocUpload\demo\Test.docx, since particular account may have numbers of Document uploaded i want to put name and like hyperlink when user click on particular filename given Document path will open... i am not sure if i am on right track as earlier i was doing some thing else to sjow doc and later on realise i was doing wrong.